# INSERT_FIRST in an Envoy filter

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar, istio-gateway

I have a cluster in which several filters are applied and I want to make sure that one of them is the first one to run.

For now this filter has this definition:

```
patch:
    operation: INSERT_BEFORE
    value:
      name: filterName
      typed_config:
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.http.lua.v2.Lua"
        inlineCode:
              ....
```

I tried changing the words "INSERT_BEFORE" to "INSERT_FIRST" but then requests began to crash.

How am I supposed to apply the "INSERT_FIRST" correctly?

Comment: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/#EnvoyFilter-Patch-Operation INSERT_FIRST should be correct, what do you mean with began to crash? Got an error message?